# Bootstrap Datepicker positioning not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using the [Bootstrap Datepicker from Eternicode](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) on my ASP.Net MVC website. The functionality works fine but I can't properly position the datepicker modal using the `orientation` option as described in the docs and in the code generator available at the link. The datepicker modal covers my input control when I click into the textbox.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker input-sm" id="datepicker" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: '0,6',
    todayHighlight: true,
    orientation: 'auto'
});
```

I've tried changing the orientation to `bottom-left`, `bottom-right` and other options to no avail. The modal always covers the input control.

Notes:

- I haven't overwritten any CSS for the datepicker plugin
- Other options, e.g., `todayHighlight` work

I'm sure I'm missing something stupid...please help?

Comment: can you recreate the issue on [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: your code is working . check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/m1zeLLaa/ if you still have the issue then post a fiddle and check the datepicker `css` and `js` files .

Comment: @JSantosh thanks a lot mate, I went ahead and just overwrote the contents of my local css and js files with what you had on the jsfiddle and the positioning is working fine now!

Comment: #SOreadytohelp @illya.

Comment: @JSantosh can you post the fiddle code as solution please? 404 in your link

Comment: @Jorge Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/santoshj/m1zeLLaa/

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem. I used the resource js(http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js) and css(http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.css) links available in the fiddle **J Santosh** recommended and it worked.
Edit: When giving the orientation value, your code would be like this

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: '0,6',
    todayHighlight: true,
    orientation: 'bottom left'
});
```

The '-' should not be there: bottom left instead of bottom-left. Use the  css and js files above if it still doesn't work.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17826532)

Comment: Errrm. Okay. Didn't see any reason to add anything more since his code clearly works and its just the resource files thats having an issue. FYI its my very first answer on here tho.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you're right. Please elaborate your answer a little bit more.